# Can New-ADGroup be used with an additional objectClass attribute values?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

So [dynamicObjects](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/carlh/2009/07/06/active-directory-dynamic-objects/) are a thing I hadn't heard of until yesterday, when [searching for a reasonable way to make a user's group membership automatically expire](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2016/03/09/previewing-server-2016-tp4-temporary-group-memberships/).

I'd like to create a group with a self-destruct time so that users can be granted access to things on a temporary basis. It doesn't seem like [New-ADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-adgroup?view=win10-ps) or [New-ADObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-adobject?view=win10-ps) support additional values for the objectClass attribute, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I tried using -OtherAttributes per MS's documentation, to pass multiple values to the objectClass attribute, but it gives a string type conversion error:

```
New-ADGroup -OtherAttributes @{'objectClass'="Group","DynamicObject";'entryTTL'=180} -Name 'Deleted in 180 Seconds' -Path $myGroupsOu -GroupScope DomainLocal


<#
New-ADGroup : Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.String'.
At line:2 char:1
+ New-ADGroup -OtherAttributes @{'objectClass'="Group","DynamicObject"; ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Deleted in 1...dc=state,dc=sbu:String) [New-ADGroup], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.InvalidCastException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADGroup
```

Per suggestion in comments, I tried other variations:

```
New-ADGroup -OtherAttributes @{'objectClass'=Group,DynamicObject;'entryTTL'=180} -Name 'Deleted in 180 Seconds' -Path $myGroupsOu -GroupScope DomainLocal
<#
At line:1 char:51
+ New-ADGroup -OtherAttributes @{'objectClass'=Group,DynamicObject;'ent ...
+                                                   ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
#>
```

One test gave what might be a very telling error message:

```
New-ADGroup -OtherAttributes @{'objectClass'="DynamicObject";'entryTTL'=180} -Name 'Deleted in 180 Seconds' -Path $myGroupsOu -GroupScope DomainLocal
<#
New-ADGroup : Illegal modify operation. Some aspect of the modification is not permitted
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ADGroup -OtherAttributes @{'objectClass'="DynamicObject";'entryTT ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CN=Deleted in 1...dc=state,dc=sbu:String) [New-ADGroup], ADIllegalModifyOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8311,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADGroup
#>
```

The "Illegal modify operation" error hints that perhaps New-ADGroup is written to create the group, then modify the group to add OtherAttributes.

I can work-around the problem by dropping into ADSI:

```
function New-ADTemporaryGroup {
    Param (
        $name,
        $path,
        $timeToLive = 180
    )
    $container = [ADSI]"LDAP://$path"

    $newGroupObj = $container.Create('Group',"cn=$name")
    $properties = @{
        'ObjectClass'=@('DynamicObject','Group')
        'entryTTL'=$timeToLive
        'sAMAccountName'=$Name
    }
    foreach ($key in $properties.Keys) {
        if ($properties[$key].Count -gt 1) {
            $newGroupObj.putEx($properties[$key].Count,$key,$properties[$key])
        } else {
            $newGroupObj.put($key, $properties[$key])
        }
    }
    $newGroupObj.SetInfo()
}


<#
> New-ADTemporaryGroup -name 'Deleted in 180 Seconds' -path $myGroupsOu -timeToLive 180

> get-adgroup 'Deleted in 180 seconds' -Properties entryttl


DistinguishedName : CN=Deleted in 180 Seconds,OU=Groups,<redacted>
entryttl          : 874
GroupCategory     : Security
GroupScope        : Global
Name              : Deleted in 180 Seconds
ObjectClass       : group
ObjectGUID        : 234ef681-53be-4c86-a944-1ba84562e710
SamAccountName    : Deleted in 180 Seconds
SID               : S-1-5-21-1292396558-1955611682-1449083124-510723

#>
```

But I would much prefer to use the AD cmdlets if they can support this operation. Does anyone have experience with this use-case?

Comment: Hi veefu; did you try this way: 
`New-ADGroup -OtherAttributes @{'objectClass'=Group,DynamicObject;'entryTTL'=180}.......`? I hope this would work.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I did give that a try too. I think that one gave me a parameter parsing error. Will update the question with that error when I get back to work.

Comment: Added test case suggested by @Am_I_Helpful

Comment: Hey, can you just try changing the entryTTL to be >=900 for the sake of testing. Also, I think you don't need to specify `'objectClass'=Group` as the cmdlet is itself for creating a group. The article says that `If an object is specified as dynamic at creation time and the entryTTL is less than that specified in Active Directory by DynamicObjectMinTTL, then the object will have an entryTTL as specified by DynamicObjectMinTTL i.e. the lower value will be ignored. `. Please give that a try, and see if helps - though I'm not very sure if it'd work.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I appreciate the brainstorming. I tried the testcase of setting only 'objectclass'='dynamicObject' but it gives an "illegal modify operation". I added that test case to the question. As for the TTL value, a higher value doesn't make a difference in the New-ADGroup code. Using the ADSI method I've successfully created objects with TTL 60000 all the way down to 180.